# Convert list to special matrix of same length

Tags: r

i'm trying to convert a list of ID's including a status to a kind of matrix of same length. I'm struggeling with the fact that i need to keep a keep a status ON / OFF until it changes.

Has anybody an idea how to start here or point me to a method that a could try to apply?

Below the input i have (left side) as well as the desired output (right side).

```
+----+--------+------+---+---+---+
| ID | STATUS | -    | a | b | c |
+----+--------+------+---+---+---+
| a  | ON     | -    | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| a  | OFF    | -    | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| a  | ON     | -    | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| b  | ON     | -    | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| b  | OFF    | -    | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| b  | ON     | -    | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| a  | OFF    | -    | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| c  | ON     | -    | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| b  | OFF    | -    | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| c  | OFF    | -    | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+----+--------+------+---+---+---+
```

Any comments or hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line creates an n by 3 matrix, `xna`, whose columns correspond to `a`, `b` and `c` and whose elements are the corresponding value of `dat$STATUS` if the  `ID` equals the column name and `NA` otherwise.  Then we convert `ON` and `OFF` to `1` and `0` giving `x01`.  Finally, we insert a dummy first row of zeros and then use `na.locf` from zoo to fill in the `NA` values removing the dummy row that was just inserted.

```
library(zoo)

xna <- ifelse(sapply(unique(dat$ID), "==", dat$ID), dat$STATUS, NA)
x01 <- (xna == "ON") + 0
data.frame(dat, na.locf(rbind(0, x01))[-1, ])
```

The result is

```
   ID STATUS a b c
1   a     ON 1 0 0
2   a    OFF 0 0 0
3   a     ON 1 0 0
4   b     ON 1 1 0
5   b    OFF 1 0 0
6   b     ON 1 1 0
7   a    OFF 0 1 0
8   c     ON 0 1 1
9   b    OFF 0 0 1
10  c    OFF 0 0 0
```

**Update** Shortened code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll check this suggestion from my side and will leave a message here.

Comment: I've checked with larger data set's as well , it works very well and also gives the desired result. Furthermore i like the idea to use this function from the zoo package instead of a loop. Thank's again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that you want to apply the state conditions sequentially and incrementally. Hence rows 4:6 have A as 1 because A was turned on in row 3, and not yet turned off.

To do that, you could do this. It uses a for loop which is not 'R-ish', but it's straightforward way to accomplish what I think you are asking

```
# the data
status <- 
  data.frame(ID=c('a','a','a','b','b','b','a','c','b','c'),
             STATUS=c('ON','OFF','ON','ON','OFF','ON','OFF','ON','OFF','OFF'),
             stringsAsFactors=F)

# unique cols
unq_cols <- unique(status$ID)

# set up, empty matrix and default row of 3 'offs'
out_mat <- NULL
temp_row <- c(0,0,0)

# apply the status conditions in order
for (i in 1:nrow(status)) {  
  col_pos <- grep(status[i, 'ID'], unq_cols)
  temp_row[col_pos] <- ifelse(status[i, 'STATUS']=='ON', 1, 0)
  out_mat <- rbind(out_mat, unname(temp_row))
}

# here's your matrix
out_mat
```

Output, which matches what you have above:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]     1    0    0
[2,]     0    0    0
[3,]     1    0    0
[4,]     1    1    0
[5,]     1    0    0
[6,]     1    1    0
[7,]     0    1    0
[8,]     0    1    1
[9,]     0    0    1
[10,]    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll also check this approach.